# Stop reloading page when we click on save , edit

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

i have made a name, email, phone number on single page , all working but  iwant to stop reload page when i click on save, edit button please give a proper detail  provide a proper code to display without reload page

```
'<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success form-control">Edit</button>`this os edit button`
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger form-control" onclick="backToEmployee()">Back</button>
    </div>
</div>'
```

`this is the code of index`

`<div class="text-center"> <a href="/Employee/Index/${data}" class="btn btn-info"> <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>it is edit button js`

`

this is the code of js`

Comment: *"i want to stop reload page when i click on save"* - generally `button` and `submit` will post the `form`, you can prevent it using [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) on the click event. show us the js though, just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, if just want to avoid click the submit button reload the page, you could just use the `e.preventDefault();` js to achieve your requirement. But this will also skip the post request for the form tag.

If you don't want to achieve post action reload the page, I suggest you could consider using ajax.

AJAX is a a web development technique that allows you to update parts of a web page without reloading it.

More details, you could refer to below example:

I modify the page to post two textbox to the backend controller method.

Below is the view codes:

```
<form asp-action="test">


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <input id="textbox1" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <input id="textbox2" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success form-control" id="edit">Edit</button>`this os edit button`
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger form-control" onclick="backToEmployee()">Back</button>
        </div>
    </div>


</form>

@section scripts {
    <script>
        $(function () {

            $("#edit").click(function (e) {
                var textbox1Content = $('#textbox1').val();
                var textbox2Content = $('#textbox2').val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'home/SaveTextboxesContents',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { textbox1: textbox1Content, textbox2: textbox2Content },
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log('Data saved successfully');
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        console.log('Error saving data');
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault();
            });


        });
                 
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
  public IActionResult SaveTextboxesContents(string textbox1, string textbox2 )
  {
      // Save the textbox content to the database or a file
      // ...
      return Json(new { success = true });
  }
```

Result:

[image]